# Excel VBA fault 1004: Method Range object_Worksheet failed

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which should run no matter what worksheet is active. However it only runs if the worksheet "data" is active. I've been trying to figure out what is wrong but can't find a solution.
So far I have checked all declarations. I have also tried fully declaring my range as suggested in some solutions.
Other solutions talk about having the code inside a worksheet as being the problem? But my code is in module 1 of the workbook. As all my macros are, So I doubt that would be the problem.

I think I am somehow not declaring the last range correctly, but I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

The last declaration (rng_nw) is giving me trouble.

```
Sub test()
Dim rapport As Worksheet
Dim data As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim cur_rng As Range
Dim sel_cel_2 As Range
Dim sel_cel_1 As Range
Dim rng_nw As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set rapport = wb.Sheets("rapport")
Set data = wb.Sheets("data")
Set cur_rng = data.Range("A2").CurrentRegion
Set sel_cel_2 = Cells(cur_rng.Rows.Count, cur_rng.Columns.Count)
Set sel_cel_1 = data.Range("k2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
Set rng_nw = Sheets("data").Range(sel_cel_2, sel_cel_1)
'Set rng_nw = data.Range(sel_cel_2, sel_cel_1)

End Sub
```

This macro is in module 1 of my workbook. Of course this is not the full macro, just the declarations that are giving me trouble. And they are just as troublesome in this small test macro ;).

Thanks in advance for your help!

The full macro is below, most of the comments are in dutch:

```
Sub Data_verversen()
'
' Data_verversen Macro
' De macro kopieert alle data uit blad rapport naar blad data en haalt vervolgens de duplicaten weg obv deal nummer'

'
Dim rapport As Worksheet
Dim data As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim plakpositie As Range
Dim r_sel1 As Range
Dim r_sel As Range
Dim d_sel As Range
Dim lastcol As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim cur_rng As Range
Dim sel_cel_2 As Range
Dim sel_cel_1 As Range
Dim rng_nw As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set rapport = wb.Sheets("rapport")
Set data = wb.Sheets("data")
Set plakpositie = data.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    'De range r_sel wijs ik in 2 stappen toe. Dat doe ik omdat de resize functie ook de range verwijzing nodig heeft en ik anders veel uit moet schrijven.
Set r_sel1 = rapport.Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0)
Set r_sel = r_sel1.Resize(r_sel1.Rows.Count - 1, r_sel1.Columns.Count)

    'to import data from Salesforce   (user has to be logged in through the salesforce.com ribbon) (connection cannot be set to background refresh)
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

    'this makes sure all calculations for the updated data are finished before the rest of the code proceeds
    Application.Calculate

    If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
        DoEvents
    End If


    'to stop the screen from updating for all the steps in this script
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Hier kopieer ik de gegevens uit range r_sel in range plakpositie. (hij plakt waarden en getalnotaties)
    r_sel.Copy
    plakpositie.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    'Ik wijs de range om duplicaten uit te verwijderen pas toe na de plakactie. Doe je dat eerder, dan bepaal je een range zonder de nieuw geplakte data
Set d_sel = data.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    'vervolgens laat ik uit de toegewezen range de duplicaten verwijderen
    d_sel.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

    data.Columns(4).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

'onderstaande set verlengd kolom K met een formule om het segment te bepalen, vervolgens worden de uitkomsten weer in waarde omgezet.
    'de formule ziet er zo uit: =DEEL(B366;VIND.ALLES("_";B366;1)+1;((VIND.ALLES("_";B366;8)-1)-VIND.ALLES("_";B366;1)))

Set cur_rng = data.Range("A2").CurrentRegion
Set sel_cel_2 = Cells(cur_rng.Rows.Count, cur_rng.Columns.Count)
Set sel_cel_1 = data.Range("k2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
'Set rng_nw = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range(sel_cel_2, sel_cel_1)
Set rng_nw = data.Range(sel_cel_2, sel_cel_1)


    rng_nw.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=MID(RC[-9],FIND(""_"",RC[-9],1)+1,((FIND(""_"",RC[-9],8)-1)-FIND(""_"",RC[-9],1)))"

    Application.Calculate

    If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
        DoEvents
    End If

    rng_nw.Copy
    rng_nw.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: `Set sel_cel_2 = Cells(cur_rng.Rows.Count, cur_rng.Columns.Count)` - you don't qualify which worksheet you want to reference.

Comment: That seems to have solved it indeed! thnx. I have now made code as following: 
`Set sel_cel_2 = data.Cells(cur_rng.Rows.Count, cur_rng.Columns.Count)`
There is just 1 thing I don't understand. If i use rng_nw. copy, it works from every sheet. But if I use rng_nw.Select, It just works if the sheet "Data" is active. Why do these 2 functions behave differently?

Comment: To use Select, I believe you have to be on that worksheet--so if you did data.Activate and then rng_nw.Select, it should work. But the Copy command you can call/use from anywhere. That's why they behave differently.

Comment: Ok. Clear explanation. Thanks!